# Are there Legion of the Damned Primaris Marines?

Tags: warhammer-40k, space-marines

There are different assumptions what the *Legion of the Damned* are exactly:

- Some Astartes that were lost in the Warp and reemerged somewhat changed
- Some dead Space Marines that are given one last chance to do something for the Imperium, aka *Saints*
- Daemons of the Starchild, i.e. the Emperors representation in the Warp as a God

So, if they are Astartes that were effected by the warp, there cannot be any Primaris Marines as they don't have access to the new Geneseed. However, if they are Space Marines given another chance to serve the empire or Daemons of the Starchild, they could appear as *Primaris Marines*. So, is there any mention that a *Primaris Marine* was among the *Legion of the Damned* or even once consisting only of *Primaris Marines*.

So, has there ever been a *Legion of the Damned Primaris Marine*?

Comment: Currently with 8th Edition there is no option for Primaris Legionnaires. GW could beef them up revealing more of their 'Damned' story or just leave it due to some secret means, but to date they have not done this. Here is a shot of the current rules page. (Note there is no Primaris in the Keywords section.) https://www.3plusplus.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/SM53-794x1024.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official in-game answer is "No" as there are no rules for Primaris LotD.  There is no official in-universe answer, but I would  say "No" there as well.  The original lore for the LotD was that the Fire Hawks chapter, lost in its entirety in a translation accident, may/are likely to be the LotD.  As they were lost before the "big reveal" of Primaris marines that would imply there are no LotD Primaris.

The theory that some dead marines are given a chance to serve the Emperor after death might imply the existance of Primaris marines.  However given the relative newness of Primaris on the field of battle they would be EXTREMELY rare to the point of non-existence.  Even at 1% attrition rates you're looking at something on the order of 100 million dead marines between the founding of the Imperium and "modern day". No matter how you slice it the rate of martyrs worthy of becoming LotD would vastly favor "normal" marines being the ones to show up.

The demons of the starchild theory is, alas, non-canon as the entire Star Child thing has been ret-conned out of existence.

On a personal note the "Fire Hawks" theory is most believable based on the available fluff, but GW has been turning back time quite a bit in the past few years so you never know what might change next.